# Why I can't call method of returns of e.getSource()?

Tags: java

I'd would know more about how `e.getSource()` works in `ActionListener` class,
My Code is Here :

```
public class ActionController implements ActionListener{

    private MyButton theButton;

    public void setTheButton(MyButton btn){
        this.theButton = btn;   
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(this.theButton == e.getSource()){
           System.out.println(e.getSource().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

In my understanding, `e.getSource()` will returns reference to the object that the event came from.

And now I don't understand why I can't call method of the source by doing like this :

```
System.out.println(e.getSource().getName());
```

I can only do By calling the private field `theButton` in the CLass, like this:

```
System.out.println(this.theButton.getName());
```

while it is already `this.theButton == e.getSource()` I can't understand why, can somebody explain more ?

---

Addition note, Why do I want to do this :

I can making a GUI with some action set to multiple button, And I want to separate the UI code and Action code in two class.
My goal is let ActionController be the middle-man, calling function in another Class (Which those function able to reuse) while it has a list linking up button's name & the function.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985507/action-listener-in-another-class-java), The answer try to passing all the ui element while class is construct. Instead of that, I prefer to pass-in the ui element dynamicly by calling method after the class construct.

If it is able to call `e.getSource().getName()`, it will be a lots clean to doing like :

```
private String[] element_funtion_table;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     String eleName = e.getSource().getName();
     String ftnName = this.getLinkedFtn(eleName);
     if(!ftnName.equals("")){
         this.callFtn(ftnName);
     }
}
```

(a part of code, you got the idea) which it makes a lot easy to manage, because 
while I can't `e.getSource().getName()` I need to store array of MyButton, instead of just names of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it to your class `MyButton`:

```
if(e.getSource() instanceof MyButton) {
    MyButton btn = (MyButton)e.getSource();
    System.out.println(btn.getName());
}
```

`e.getSource()` returns `Object` type. There is no method named `getName()` within class `Object`. Hence compiler complaints about it.

*Edited*:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() instanceof MyButton) {
        MyButton btn = (MyButton)e.getSource();
        String ftnName = this.getLinkedFtn(btn.getName());
        if(!ftnName.equals("")){
            this.callFtn(ftnName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("unknown ftnName");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("unknown source");
    }
}
```